# How's processing take Arduino two different values?

Tags: processing, arduino-uno

I used readstring() to get the str_values .But how can I identify and divide those values from serial.I'm rookie for arduino and proceesing.But It's true that processing is more easier for rookie.

I'm asking how can I get value from first to second.Is arduino have pointer for files to files?

Processing

```
if(comPort.available() > 0){
    //serialEvent();
    pulse = comPort.readString();
    //print(pulse);
    int x1 = distanceLeft;
    int x2 = distanceRight;
    if(val >= 30){
      X2 -= 20;}
    if(val >= 15 && val <= 30){
      X2 -= 10;}
    else if(val >= 5 && val <= 15){
      X2 += 10;}
    else if(val <= 5){
      X2 += 20;}
  }
```

Arduino

```
int const trigRightPin= 3;
int const echoRightPin= 2;
int const trigLeftPin= 13;
int const echoLeftPin= 12;
int durationLeft;
int durationRight;
int distanceLeft;
int distanceRight;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(trigRightPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigLeftPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoRightPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(echoLeftPin,INPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigRightPin,LOW);
  digitalWrite(trigLeftPin,LOW);
  }
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigRightPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigRightPin,LOW);
  durationRight = pulseIn(echoRightPin,HIGH); 
  distanceRight = durationRight*0.034/2; 
  digitalWrite(trigLeftPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigLeftPin,LOW);
  durationLeft = pulseIn(echoLeftPin,HIGH);
  if(durationLeft != 0)
    distanceLeft = durationLeft*0.034/2; 
  Serial.print("R");
  Serial.print(distanceRight);
  Serial.print("CM\n""L");
  Serial.print(distanceLeft);
  Serial.print("CM""\n");
  }
```

God show me the path.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an integer array on the Arduino side.  The integers in the array are sent one at a time with a comma in between the two values.  The second value is terminated by a line feed by using println() instead of print() as it is sent.  Arduino serial sends the integer values as a string.  On the Processing side the string is read until the line feed is encountered, at which point the string is terminated. The resultant string then contains the two values separated by a comma. The string is next split at the comma into a String array containing two elements. The first string element (myData[0]) is converted to an integer and saved as x1.  The second string element (myData[1]) is also converted to an integer and becomes x2.  Example code is given below to demonstrate how it works:

**Arduino code:**

```
int randNumber[2];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // print a random number from 0 to 299
  randNumber[0] = random(300);
  Serial.print(randNumber[0]);
  Serial.print(','); // Comma separated values
  // print a random number from 10 to 19
  randNumber[1] = random(10, 20);
  Serial.println(randNumber[1]); // line feed terminated
  delay(50);
}
```

**Processing code:**

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;    // The serial port
String inStr;    // Input string from serial port
int lf = 10;    // ASCII linefeed
int x1, x2;

void setup() {
  surface.setVisible(false); // Output is in console at bottom of editor
  // List all the available serial ports:
  printArray(Serial.list());
  // Enter device number for your system
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[4], 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil(lf);
}

void draw() {
}

void serialEvent( Serial myPort) {
  //'\n' (line feed) is delimiter indicating end of packet
  inStr = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  //make sure our data isn't empty before continuing
  if (inStr != null) {
    //trim whitespace and formatting characters (like carriage return and/or line feed)
    inStr = trim(inStr);  //Data is sent as a string
    println("inStr = ", inStr);
    String[] myData = split(inStr, ','); // String is split into array at comma
    printArray(myData);
    x1 = Integer.valueOf(myData[0]); // Array elements are converted back to integers
    println("x1 = ", x1);
    x2 = Integer.valueOf(myData[1]);
    println("x2 = ", x2);
  }
}
```